# How to convert multiple street address into latitude longitude and display it on google map in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, angular8

I have tried npm modules, google developer documentation (which is specific to javascript) and various other sites but there is no specific documentation on
how to convert multiple street address into latitude and longitude and display marks on that location.

Answer (score 0):

To convert addresses into lat/lng coordinates you can use Google's Geocoding API, and to place markers on a map using those retrieved coordinates, use the JavaScript API.

There are a few Angular-based map modules you may want to install. Take a look at my [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-geocoding-du1yrh) which is a fork from [angular-google-maps-demo-geocoding](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-geocoding) which is a fork from [angular-google-maps-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo).

It shows one way in which you can place multiple markers on a map (for "london" and "oxford") using Google's JavaScript API and its Geocoder service. Remember to add your own API key before running it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well your stackblitz demo is not showing markers on map for "london" and "oxford". Please have a look at it. https://prnt.sc/p9mpsp

Comment: You need to add your API key (in app.module.ts), otherwise the Geocoder doesn't work. Also make sure your key belongs to a project that has billing enabled and both the Geocoding API and JavaScript API enabled. Let me know if it works for you once you run the app with your key.

Comment: @VirendraMaheta heya were you able to run my stackblitz? do you need further help with your question?